# How to send data from business logic class to UI while using BackgroundWorker in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I've two classes in my C# project. One for UI and another for Business Logic (BL). I've used BackgroundWorker in the UI project to call a method in BL which will handle a time consuming task (database backup). However, I couldn't send percentage completion from the BL to UI. What is the best way to achieve this?

Note: UI references the BL project

Comment: At least you could show what you have already done. Have you tried `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event?

Comment: I prefer using the ProgressChanged Event in my projects, please give us a code snippet, so we can see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dispatcher.Invoke to write to UI
Something like
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Status.Content = "your text");

Answer (score 0):

In winforms you typically use a pattern similar to the following in your control/form.

```
public void UpdatePercentage(double percentage) {
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        Invoke(new Action<double>(UpdatePercentage), percentage);
        // You could also use BeginInvoke if you don't care about the return value
        return;
    }
    // we are now on the ui thread and can update what we want
    myLabel.Text = Math.Round((percentage * 100), 2).ToString();
}
```

References:

- [`Control.InvokeRequired`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Control.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Patrick, when I put your sample code in the BL, it doesn't recognize Invoke. Where should I put the method UpdatePercentage?

Comment: That's the reason I mentioned you should put it in your control. The InvokeRequired and Invoke functionality is defined in the Control class.